# Android RecyclerView - When i change the first item, the last change too

Tags: android

I Apologize for my english, i'm french.

I have a Problem with List in RecyclerView. In effect, I want to change the TextView of items Dynamically. But, when i change the textView of the first item, the last changed too. I use a CardView to represent my item.

I don't think it was my code, but a particularity of RecyclerView.

thank you in advance

**my adapter**

```
public class CardAgendaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private static final int LENGTH = 7;
    static private final int test[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    private  int[][] dispo = new int[7][4];
    private Context context;
    private int startHour = -1;
    private int finishHour = -1;
    private int startMinute = -1;
    private int finishMinute = -1;
    private int pos = 0;
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder holderr;

    public CardAgendaAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
            dispo[i][0] = -1;
            dispo[i][1] = -1;
            dispo[i][2] = -1;
            dispo[i][3] = -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        return test[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return LENGTH;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_modify_card, parent, false);
        View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_card, parent, false);

        switch (viewType) {
            case 0: return new ViewHolder0(view1);
            case 1: return new ViewHolder2(view2);
        }
        return null;
    }

    static final  String days[] = {"Lundi", "Mardi","Mercredi","Jeudi","Vendredi","Samedi","Dimanche"};

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 1 :
                ViewHolder2 v2 = (ViewHolder2) holder;
                v2.setDay(days[position]);
                v2.setImage(position);
                Log.d("item : ", String.valueOf(position));
                v2.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        pos = position;
                        holderr = holder;
                        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(context, listener, 0, 0, true);
                        timePickerDialog.show();
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 0:
                ViewHolder0 v0 = (ViewHolder0) holder;
                v0.setTextCard();
                v0.setDay(days[position]);
                v0.setImage(position);
                break;
        }
    }

    public String testText(int startHour, int startMinute, int finishHour, int finishMinute) {
        return String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml("Vous êtes disponnible de <b>" + String.valueOf(startHour) + "h" + String.valueOf(startMinute) +"</b> à <b> "+ String.valueOf(finishHour)+"h" +String.valueOf(finishMinute)+"</b>"));
    }

    public void setHour(int poistion, int startHour, int startMinute, int finishHour, int finishMinute, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        dispo[poistion][0] = startHour;
        dispo[poistion][1] = startMinute;
        dispo[poistion][2] = finishHour;
        dispo[poistion][3] = finishMinute;

        switch (getItemViewType(poistion)) {
            case 1:
                ViewHolder2 v2 = (ViewHolder2) holder;
                v2.setTextCard(startHour,startMinute,finishHour,finishMinute);
                //view.findViewById(R.id.button_add).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //view.findViewById(R.id.button_modify).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        Log.d("Jour : " + poistion, String.valueOf(dispo[poistion][0]));
        Log.d("Jour : " + poistion, String.valueOf(dispo[poistion][1]));
        Log.d("Jour : " + poistion, String.valueOf(dispo[poistion][2]));
        Log.d("Jour : " + poistion, String.valueOf(dispo[poistion][3]));
    }

    private void reinitHour() {
        startHour = -1;
        startMinute = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog2;
        Log.d("Picker la", "AVANT");
        timePickerDialog2 = new TimePickerDialog(context, listener, 0, 0, true);
        Log.d("Picker la", "APRÈS");
        timePickerDialog2.show();
    }

    protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfDay) {
                    if (startHour == -1 && startMinute == -1) {
                        startHour = hourOfDay;
                        startMinute = minuteOfDay;

                        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog2;
                        timePickerDialog2 = new TimePickerDialog(context, listener, 0, 0, true);

                        timePickerDialog2.show();
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Heure de depart : " + startHour + " minutes de départ : " + startMinute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        finishHour = hourOfDay;
                        finishMinute = minuteOfDay;
                        Log.d("ça passe la", "FINNNNNNNN");
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Heure de fin : " + finishHour + " minutes de fin : " + finishMinute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        setHour(pos,startHour,startMinute,finishHour,finishMinute, holderr);
                        reinitHour();
                    }
                }
            };

    class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView disponibility;
        ImageView imageView;
        Button add;
        Button modify;

        public ViewHolder2(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            disponibility = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
            add = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
            modify = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_modify);
        }

        public void setTextCard(int startHour, int startMinute, int finishHour, int finishMinute) {
            disponibility.setText(Html.fromHtml("Vous êtes disponnible de     <b>" + String.valueOf(startHour) + "h" + String.valueOf(startMinute) +"</b>     à <b> "+ String.valueOf(finishHour)+"h" +String.valueOf(finishMinute)+"    </b>"));  
        }

        public void setDay(String str) {
            if (title != null) {
                title.setText(str);
            }
        }

        public void setImage(int position) {
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageResource(getId(position+1));
            }
        }

        private int getId(int position) {
            Context context = imageView.getContext();
            int id =     context.getResources().getIdentifier("tennis"+position, "drawable",     context.getPackageName());
            return id;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textCard;
        TextView textTitle;
        ImageView imageView;
        public ViewHolder0(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            textCard = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
            textTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
        }

        public void setDay(String str) {
            if (textTitle != null) {
                textTitle.setText(str);
            }
        }

        public void setTextCard() {
            textCard.setText(Html.fromHtml("Vous êtes disponnible de     <b>17h30</b> à <b>18h30</b>"));
        }

        public void setImage(int position) {
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageResource(getId(position + 1));
            }
        }

        private int getId(int position) {
            Context context = imageView.getContext();
            int id =     context.getResources().getIdentifier("tennis"+position, "drawable",     context.getPackageName());
            return id;
        }
    }    
}
```

**agenda_card.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
app:elevation="0dp"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_image_height"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/tennis1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_title_height"
        android:text="Lundi"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_above="@+id/card_text"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/card_text"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/card_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Vous n'avez pas ajouté de disponibilité"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/article_subheading"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:text="AJOUTER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Yes we want your code, your RecyclerAdapter and others

Comment: I change my Post :)

Comment: What do you mean with _change the textView_?

Comment: just, set a different text of this textView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to your binding and how adapters work.

Like the name already tells you, views of your adapter get recycled to be shown at another position if the original position is not displayed anymore. But your code for `ViewHolder2` doesn't update all data of the view holder.

```
ViewHolder2 v2 = (ViewHolder2) holder;
v2.setDay(days[position]);
v2.setImage(position);
Log.d("item : ", String.valueOf(position));
v2.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pos = position;
        holderr = holder;
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(context, listener, 0, 0, true);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

This is missing a call to `v2.setTextCard()`. So you need to make sure somehow, that `disponibility` is set correctly. This generally applies to all fields of any view holder.

Try to generify your adapter a little more. Also it comes in handy to have an `update()` method on the view holder to handle changes.

As a side note, your `onCreateViewHolder()` method could be a little more efficient. At the moment you are inflating two views each time, even though you only use one.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
switch (viewType) {
    case 0: return new ViewHolder0(inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_modify_card, parent, false));
    case 1: return new ViewHolder2(inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_card, parent, false));
    default: return null;
}
```

Comment: Hey ! Thx for your answer but i don't understand all. In effect, can you explain "This is missing a call to v2.setTextCard(). So you need to make sure somehow, that disponibility is set correctly. This generally applies to all fields of any view holder." please ?

Comment: Imagine you call `setTextCard()` on the first view holder.Then this view gets recycled and shown as the last element. The text is already set. So it displays the same text at the last position. This can be solved by calling `setTextCard()` with the updated data or `disponibility.setText(null)` to remove the text.

Comment: Ah okey !!! But, How can i keep the text when the view is again shown ?

Comment: Good to hear. You too.